# How to declare tags aliases with acts_as_taggable_on in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

The acts_as_taggable_on implementation worked quite well, but I also need to declare tags aliases.

I've found a plugin that claimed to do so, [acts_as_taggable_with_aliases](https://github.com/Sjlver/acts_as_taggable_with_aliases), but last commit was in 2009 and is not on the gem repositories, so I assume the project is dead by now.

There is any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you look at the source to see how `_with_aliases` did it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create your own models to support this (and anything else you want)...

I think you can achieve that by doing something like:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :tag_id
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end

class ModelIWantToBeTagged < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelTagging
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
end

module ModelTagging
    def add_tag(tag_name)           
        tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_tag(tag_name)
        tagging = Tagging.new
        tagging.taggable_id = self.id
        tagging.taggable_type = get_class_name
        tagging.tag_id = tag.id
        tagging.save!
    end

    def remove_tag(tag_name)
        tag = Tag.find_by_tag(tag_name)         
        Tagging.where(:tag_id => tag).delete_all        
    end

    private
    def get_class_name
        self.class.name
    end
end
```

This way you can any behavior and data to your tags.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to the code of `acts_as_taggable_with_aliases`. All is inside. You can see if it's allways compatible with `acts_as_taggable` and check if you can try maintain it.